# What is the Degrowth perspective on ad blocking and online advertising?

Tags: green-it, internet, degrowth

From a [Degrowth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrowth) perspective, how would one argue in favour or against ad blocking and online advertising?

*Degrowth* is a political, economic, and social movement based on ecological economics, anti-consumerist and anti-capitalist ideas that tries to address the limits to growth dilemma (constraints of a finite planet).

Surely, online advertising fuels consumption. Yet it is also a potential source of income for anti-consumerist alternatives and blocking advertising thus closes this opportunity of income generation.

Comment: There's also an associated energy cost in running the ad servers and transmitting all the data.

Comment: Not to mention a big difference between trying to convince people to buy something new, and advertising things like seed swaps and hand-tool sharpening.

Comment: Interesting thought. I haven't thought about using ads to promote second-hand products and goods & services for self-sustained living.

Comment: The irony is that this site is supported and offered for free thanks to online advertising (through the parent site stack overflow -- see [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/15/how-we-make-money-at-stack-overflow-2016-edition/) for an explanation).

Answer (score 2):

If you use services which are paid for by someone else, through advertising or because they like the views that the editor is pushing, then you forfeit an element of control and knowledge about service that you are using. When using a search engine that is provided by a company that has a focus on growth you are supporting that company by adding to their profile.

However, this is not an argument against all ads. Ads which have been selected to be compatible with sustainability (e.g. as used by [Ecosia](https://whatisthebusinessmodelof.com/business-models/ecosia-business-model/)) should be compatible with Degrowth.

Hence, I suggest, it is the prevalent economic model which is supported by the majority of ads which is the problem, rather than the adds themselves. Avoid, as far as possible, services from companies which have a business model which is incompatible with sustainability ... even if they are free.